# One-sided tangents?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I was trying to solve this problem:

**Find the angle between the one-sided tangents to the curve at the point x = 0.**
$$f(x) =\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}$$
I obtained the point (0,0) and I have computed the first derivative 
$$f'(x)=\frac{-xe^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}$$ but when I try to substitute by $0$ I get that the slope is $0$. How can I solve it ?

Comment: but $e^{-0}=1$ so you can not get $0/0$

Comment: Yeah I see, but then I get an slope equal to 0. Then the tangent line is a vertical line y=0???

Comment: It might help to remember that $\sqrt{e^a} = \left(e^a\right)^{1/2} = e^{a/2}$!!

Comment: for $x=0$ we find $y=1$

Comment: @Evoked the line $y = 0$ and in general, lines with zero slope, are horizontal, not vertical.  But yes: the tangent line will have slope $0$.

Comment: Then, how can I find the angle between the tangents?I only got one tangent, so I don't know with what other line should I work.

Comment: $\sqrt {e^{-x^2}} = e^{-\frac {x^2}{2}}$  The graph of which is our old friend the "Bell Curve"

Comment: Why is it $(0,1)$? When I substitute $x=0$ in the function, $f(0)=0$

Comment: $f(0) = \sqrt {e^{0}} = \sqrt {1} = 1$

Comment: My fault, I forgot to put the function correctly @DougM

Comment: But the answer I am given @MathLover is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: IMHO the person who assigned this exercise had in mind this function $$f(x)=\sqrt{e^{-\left| x\right| }}$$ which has two tangents $$y=\frac{x}{2}+1;\;y=-\frac{x}{2}+1$$ which form an angle of about $126°52'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes:

First,
$$f'(x) = \frac{xe^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}}. \tag 1$$

Now, it is easy to prove that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f'(x)=1, \tag 2$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f'(x)=-1. \tag 3$$
Therefore, the tangents are $y=x$ and $y=-x$, and the angle between them is $\pi/2$.